# SQL select that compare date against previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

How from that data I show only the names that the Date "END" is bigger than the next "Begin" Date.

e.g. Peter shouldn't be shown as his first row "END" date is 2019-12-31 and his next "Begin" Date is 2020-01-01 so 2019<2020. Now for John first row "End" date is 2021-12-31 which is bigger than next Row "Begin" date 2020-03-01.

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║  name   ║   Begin    ║    End     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Peter   ║ 2016-01-01 ║ 2019-12-31 ║
║ Peter   ║ 2020-01-01 ║ 2020-12-31 ║
║ John    ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 2021-12-31 ║
║ John    ║ 2020-03-01 ║ 2022-03-01 ║
║ Mary    ║ 2018-02-01 ║ 2022-01-31 ║
║ Mary    ║ 2020-01-01 ║ 2022-01-01 ║
║ Charles ║ 2019-07-01 ║ 2021-06-30 ║
║ Charles ║ 2020-03-01 ║ 2022-03-01 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

So from this data how do I get only

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║  name   ║   Begin    ║    End     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ John    ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 2021-12-31 ║
║ John    ║ 2020-03-01 ║ 2022-03-01 ║
║ Mary    ║ 2018-02-01 ║ 2022-01-31 ║
║ Mary    ║ 2020-01-01 ║ 2022-01-01 ║
║ Charles ║ 2019-07-01 ║ 2021-06-30 ║
║ Charles ║ 2020-03-01 ║ 2022-03-01 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Can you have more than two rows?

Answer (score 1):

You want rows whose `end` date is greater than the next `begin` for the same `name` You can use window functions for this

```
select t.name, tLbegin, t.end
from (
    select
        t.*,
        lead(t.begin) over(partition by t.name order by t.begin) lead_begin
    from mytable t
) t
where t.end > t.lead_begin or lead_begin is null
```

Note that this would not remove the second record for `'John'` (since it does not have a next record).

Side note: `begin` and `end` are reserved words in SQL, hence not good choices for column names.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want rows with overlaps, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.end > t.start and
                    t2.start < t.start
             );
```